# I'm trying to store ID of three employees using Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: c, dynamic

**Code -**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *e;
    int len;

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the size of the ID of the Employee %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &len);

        printf("Enter Employee ID of Employee %d\n", i);
        scanf("%s", &e);
    }

    e = (char *)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("ID of Employee %d is %s\n", i, e);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Terminal -**

```
Enter the size of the ID of the Employee 1
2
Enter Employee ID of Employee 1
A2
Enter the size of the ID of the Employee 2
2
Enter Employee ID of Employee 2
A7
Enter the size of the ID of the Employee 3
3
Enter Employee ID of Employee 3
AA1
```

**Expected Output -**

```
ID of Employee 1 is A2
ID of Employee 2 is A7
ID of Employee 3 is AA1
```

**Output I am getting -**

```
»D of Employee 1 is Φ
»D of Employee 2 is Φ
»D of Employee 3 is Φ
```

*Here, »D and Φ refers to Garbage Value that changes every time when I run it in another terminal*

> I'm just learning the basics of Dynamic Memory Allocation but getting problems even in that
> Pls Help

Comment: @JustASimpleLonelyProgrammer They still will only have enough memory allocated in that case for just one of the employees.

Comment: `&e` should just be `e`.

Comment: You need an array of pointers.

Comment: @BillLynch You're right. I should've checked the full code before posting the comment.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, It worked

Comment: first you `scanf()` into an uninitialized pointer `e`, then you call `e = malloc()` but don't write anything into the array vou have created. That can't work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments above, you have a glaring mistake in that you are attempting to use the memory before you've allocated it. Try this:

```
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_EMP 3

int main()
{
    char *e[MAX_EMP];
    int len[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_EMP; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the size of the ID of the Employee %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf(" %d ", &len[i]);

        e[i] = (char*)malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
        printf("Enter Employee ID of Employee %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf(" %s ", e[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_EMP; i++)
        printf("ID of Employee %d is %s\n", i + 1, e[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Also, note that memory resources are rarely at such a premium that dynamic memory allocation makes sense for such small strings. It's more practical to just do this:

```
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_EMP 3
#define MAX_LEN 10

int main()
{
    char e[MAX_EMP][MAX_LEN + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_EMP; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Employee ID of Employee #%d\n", i + 1);
        fgets(e[i],MAX_LEN + 1,stdin);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_EMP; i++)
        printf("ID of Employee #%d is %s\n", i + 1, e[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- you need to store the data for every employee (probably in an array)
- in `scanf("%s", something)` `something` must be of type `char *`. In your code it is `char **`.
- don't use scanf %s because it assumes the buffer is large enough for the input. Use `fgets` or scanf %ms
- in new versions there is also `scanf("%ms", something)` where `something` is `char **`. It allocates the string and stores the pointer to it in `*something`
- having `i` start at 0 is easier when working with arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *ids[3];   // store the id for every employee, no need to store the length

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the size of the ID of the Employee %d\n", i + 1);
        int len;
        scanf("%d", &len);
        ids[i] = malloc(len + 1);   // no need to cast the pointer, sizeof(char) is always 1

        printf("Enter Employee ID of Employee %d\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", ids[i]);   // use fgets here
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("ID of Employee %d is %s\n", i + 1, ids[i]);
        free(ids[i]);   // free it when you are done with it
    }

    return 0;
}
```